# WEBrick error loading asset files

Tags: ruby, webrick

When I run an instance of WEBrick server and point my browser to localhost:2000/so_question, the server throws the following errors:
i. ERROR /some_image.jpg not found.
ii. ERROR /jquery.min.js not found.

sample code:

```
require 'webrick'; include WEBrick
s = HTTPServer.new Port: 2000

class SoQuestion < HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet

def do_GET req, resp
  resp.status = 200
  resp['Content-Type'] = 'text/html'
  resp.body = prep_body
end

def prep_body
  body = %(
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
)
  body << '<p>Hello, world!</p>'
  body << "<img src='some_image.jpg'>"
  body << "<script src='jquery.min.js'></script>"
  body << '</body></html>'
end

end

s.mount '/so_question', SoQuestion
trap('INT'){s.shutdown}
s.start
```

How to fix these errors? Plz, suggest a pure-Ruby solution(no gems, plz).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mount point to serve your statics file.

Put this line below after your `s.mount "/so_question"`

`s.mount "/", WEBrick::HTTPServlet::FileHandler, './'`

And then the Webrick will serve the statics file at `./` basedir